# IIS Reverse Proxy or ARR

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

I have the need to do a reverse proxy but the peculiarity is that it should be done to a specific path.

By declaring different websites I can do

`localhost:80` - > `localhost:7200`

but the urls should be

`localhost:80/myDir` - > `localhost:7200/myDir`

Answer (score 0):

ARR provides both capabilities, I've had a lot of success with it. Using the ARR rules will give you a lot of flexibility at both the TCP/IP layer and the HTTP protocol layer.

Go into your IIS website that binds to port 80 (HTTP) and select "URL Rewrite", then click "Add Rule", then select "Reverse Proxy":

[Reverse Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEi78.png)

You will be presented with this page, enter your settings here:

[Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCh6p.png)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on your answer, perhaps provide some example ARR rules to help the OP address their issue?

Comment: Thank you but Add Reverse Proxy Rules -> Inbound Rules won't allow me to specify the directory